# Building NPAPI plugin without X11 in QTWebkit?

Tags: qt, plugins, qtwebkit

All,
 Is it possible to build the NPAPI plugin without X11 in QTWebkit.
 We have built QTWebkit with directfb as backend (without X11) and it renders fine in the platform. 
 Our next requirement is  to build the plugin for QTWebkit. 
 Seems like NPAPI plugin is not supported in non X11 windows system.
 Have anybody tried ? and Is there any alternative approach available to develop plugin on qtwebwit without X11.

Cheers!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the plugin?

Comment: Our Application should be able to add various plugins in order to extend its features ... The immediate requirement is to add video plugin. Also the plugin objects should also be invoked from java script.